# regex for serial number in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var serialNumber = $('#SerialNumber').val();
var serialNumberPattern = new RegExp('^[\s\da-zA-z\-.]+$');

if (!serialNumberPattern.test(serialNumber)) {
}
```

Above is the code I am using to validate a serial number which has alphanumeric characters, dots (.), dashes (-), and slashes (/) in it but somehow it's not working. Where am I going wrong? Please help.

Comment: escape all the backslashes one more time. How many times?

Comment: doesn't the dot should be slashed too ? like `\.`

Comment: Use a RegExp literal, i.e. `/^[\s\da-z\/.-]+$/i`.

Comment: could you may provide us with 2 serials that should be proved... one that should work and one that should fail ?

Answer (score 0):

When you're passing regex to RegExp constructor which uses `"` as regex delimiter, you have to escape all the backslashes one more time. Or otherwise it would be treated as an escape sequence.

```
var serialNumberPattern = new RegExp("^[\\s\\da-zA-Z.-]+$");
```

> alphanumeric,dot(.),Dash(-),Slash(/) in it.

```
var serialNumberPattern = new RegExp("^[\\da-zA-Z./-]+$");
```

Comment: may I know the reason?

Comment: I don't know, but probably they want you to use RegExp literal.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `/^[\s\da-zA-Z\-.\/]+$/`, it's simple and works just fine.

You should only use the `RegExp` constructor when parts of the expression use a variable. This is not true in your case and just adds additional confusion.

```js
document.write(/^[\s\da-zA-Z\-.\/]+$/.test('23 43-89'))
```

Comment: I tried this and it is showing false when tested 23 43-89